# Is this the proper way to set up MongoDB connection pooling?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to use connection pooling for my MongoDB server but it seems like the connections I create when I first initialize the application, they don't even get touched. I'm using Spring Data MongoDB.

Here is my configuration for the root-context.xml

```
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" host="localhost"
    port="27017">
    <mongo:client-options connect-timeout="10000"
        connections-per-host="50" min-connections-per-host="5"
        threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="10" />
</mongo:mongo-client>
<mongo:db-factory dbname="project" mongo-ref="mongoClient" />
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.stackoverflow.repositories" />
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```